# ReactJS, Golang server CORS content-type trouble

Tags: reactjs, go, cors

So I've been trying to connect my reactJS local client to my Golang local server with a POST request, but I keep getting this error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I've already tried to change the heathers on the server and client side multiple times, but I've got no luck so far. FYI everything works just fine in Postman.

This is my code on client side

```
const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                First: this.state.first,
                Second: this.state.second,
                Symbol: this.state.symbol,
                Date: this.state.date,
            })
        };
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/', requestOptions)
            .then(response => { return response.json() })
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ result: data });
            })
        .catch(console.log)
}
```

and this is it on the server side

```
type Params struct {
    First string
    Second string
    Symbol string
    Date string
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

       if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there")
            return
        }


        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

        var params Params
        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&params)

        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", err)
            return
        }

        // somthing else here

    })
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing content-type in *"Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response"*. i.e. you are missing `w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")`

Comment: In addition to @mkopriva's comment, you're not handling the preflight (`OPTIONS`) request properly. Why not use some good CORS middleware, such as [rs/cors](https://github.com/rs/cors), instead of implementing CORS "manually"?

Comment: @jub0bs this is for a college project, and I'm not allowed to use any middleware :c

Comment: @iiiasminx Ok. Just be aware that, unless you handle the preflight request properly on the server side, if you send a cross-origin request to that server from a browser, it won't work; CORS preflight will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I was missing a header.

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
```

credit goes to @mkopriva!